# Billiards or Snooker Data

Tags: data-request, sports

I am interested in developing an index for rating for player ability in billiards or snooker. To do so I was hoping to get a dataset consisting of attempted shots and their success with other factors (distance from object ball, angle of cut, distance from pocket) etc.

Is there any dataset that exists like this?

Comment: http://www.snookerdatabase.co.uk/ will be almost completely useless to you, but I'm under quota for pointless posts today. You might find video of pool/snooker games and generate this yourself, but ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My favourite source for all-things-snooker is [CueTracker](http://cuetracker.net/).

It features high-completeness at all times and a plethora of statistics covering all manner of things (from both professional and amateur tours), all put together and maintained by an amateur snooker player and enthusiast.